# 504 gateway time-out nginx нет доступа к конфигам nginx

Tags: php, nginx, http

Выгружаю большой файл. Планируется что он будет выгружаться 10-15 минут. В процессе выгрузки nginx пишет 504 ошибку. Доступа к конфигам у меня нету. Как справиться с этой ошибкой средствами PHP ?